# Saving multiple contented itable div elements

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I have a bit a javascript that will save the editable content by the element id, and use local storage so when the user returns the changes will still display. However I am trying to find out a way to do the same functionality for multiple elements.

Here Is the code I have that works for 1 element

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function updatepicture(pic){
    document.getElementById("productImage").setAttribute("src",pic);
}
function saveEdits(){
    var editElem1 = document.getElementById("edit1");
    var userVersion1 = editElem1.innerHTML;
    localStorage.userEdits1 = userVersion1;
    document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="Edits saved!";
}
function checkEdits(){
    if(localStorage.userEdits1!=null)
    document.getElementById("edit1").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits1;
}
</script>
```

And here is what I have so far for multiple elements, but they are all returning the value of the first edited element.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function updatepicture(pic){
    document.getElementById("productImage").setAttribute("src",pic);
}
function saveEdits(){
    var editElem1 = document.getElementById("edit1");
    var editElem2 = document.getElementById("edit2");
    var editElem3 = document.getElementById("edit3");
    var editElem4 = document.getElementById("edit4");
    var editElem5 = document.getElementById("edit5");
    var editElem6 = document.getElementById("edit6");
    var userVersion1 = editElem1.innerHTML;
    var userVersion2 = editElem2.innerHTML;
    var userVersion3 = editElem3.innerHTML;
    var userVersion4 = editElem4.innerHTML;
    var userVersion5 = editElem5.innerHTML;
    var userVersion6 = editElem6.innerHTML;
    localStorage.userEdits1 = userVersion1;
    localStorage.userEdits2 = userVersion2;
    localStorage.userEdits3 = userVersion3;
    localStorage.userEdits4 = userVersion4;
    localStorage.userEdits5 = userVersion5;
    localStorage.userEdits6 = userVersion6;
    document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="Edits saved!";
}
function checkEdits(){
    if(localStorage.userEdits1!=null)
    document.getElementById("edit1").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits1;
    else if(localStorage.userEidts2!=null)
    document.getElementById("edit2").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits2;
}
</script>
```

Any help as how to save multiple elements would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it was simply using else if as opposed to if

```
    if(localStorage.userEdits1!=null)
document.getElementById("edit1").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits1;
else if(localStorage.userEidts2!=null)
document.getElementById("edit2").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits2;
```

changed to

```
    if(localStorage.userEdits1!=null)
document.getElementById("edit1").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits1;
    if(localStorage.userEidts2!=null)
document.getElementById("edit2").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits2;
```